# R markdown not rendering Latex from HTML

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown

I am trying to knit a document using plotly to generate the images and rmarkdown. Below is a basic example:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(plotly)
library(webshot)
library(webshot2)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. It is a test.

```{r test, echo=FALSE}
x <- seq(-1, 1, 0.1)
y <- dnorm(x, 0, 0.5)
pl1 <- plot_ly(x=x, y=y, type='scatter', mode='lines') %>%
  config(mathjax='cdn') %>%
    plotly::layout(
      showlegend=TRUE,
      legend=list(itemsizing='trace', orientation='h',
        xanchor='center', x=0.5), margin=list(b=80, l=45, r=30, t=80),
      title=list(text=
          TeX("M \\text{ updates for } N=n=1 \\text{ for } P(update) = \\gamma_{i}.")))
# pl1
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widget = pl1, file = "pl1.html")
webshot(url = "pl1.html", file = "pl1.pdf")
````

The problem is that when I knit the document, the htmlwidgets function generates the correct rendering of Latex (top image), but the webshot function does not (bottom image). Also, I have tried using `fig.show='hold'` but this doesn't help either.

I have also tried using `webshot2` and, when using `webshot` I have installed `webshot::install_phantomjs()`

[image: The correct rendering (html from above markdown code)]

[image: The incorrect rendering (jpg snapshot from pdf generated by above markdown code)]

Comment: You can change your output to `html_document` and then when the HTML is rendered into the document, you can then `"print to PDF"` from the browser to maintain the HTML look, and have the PDF document

Comment: I will certainly try that.

Comment: Ok. I tried that but for some reason I cannot figure, all the of the latex is being rendered in bold.